# Get counts of unique lists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

I have a pandas Dataframe where one of the columns is full of lists:

```
import pandas    
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, [a, b, c]],
                       [2, [d, e, f]],
                       [3, [a, b, c]]])
```

And I'd like to make a pivot table that shows the list and a count of occurrences

```
List     Count
[a,b,c]  2
[d,e,f]  1
```

Because list is a non-hashable type, what aggregate functions could do this?

Comment: `df[1].map(tuple).value_counts()`. `_.map(tuple)` is important since `list` is not hashable. Using `list` would raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip a list of rows and a list of counts, then make a dataframe from the zip object:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']],
                   [2, ['d', 'e', 'f']],
                   [3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]])
rows = []
counts = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1] not in rows:
        rows.append(row[1])
        counts.append(1)
    else:
        counts[rows.index(row[1])] += 1
df = pandas.DataFrame(zip(rows, counts))
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']],
           [2, ['d','e', 'f']],
           [3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]])
print(df[1])
df[1] = df[1].map(tuple)
#Thanks Ch3steR
df2 = pandas.pivot_table(df,index=df[1], aggfunc='count')
print(df2)
```